# Arity of a function

Tags: clojurescript, arity

Is there a way in clojurescript to check what the available arity implementations of a given cljs function are?

Answer (score 1):

If you're running Emacs with nREPL, as explained on [this gist](https://web.archive.org/web/20140803115523/https://gist.github.com/rkneufeld/5126926), when your text cursor is near the function name Emacs will show the signatures of the function in the message area.

Like that:
[image: emacs-screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

The only answer from Rodrigo Taboada is dated and now lots of new tools are out.

### Light Table and Fighwheel

I think nowadays [Light Table](http://lighttable.com/) is one of the best tools for ClojureScript, especially when coupled with [Figwheel](https://github.com/bhauman/lein-figwheel). More info for [using LT with Figwheel](https://github.com/bhauman/lein-figwheel/wiki/Running-figwheel-with-LightTable).

In Light Table to check a function signature you can simply put the cursor over the function name and hit `Ctrl-D` to toggle the inline documentation.

[image: LT inline doc]

### Emacs and Cider + Figwheel

For Emacs [Cider](https://cider.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) coupled with [Figwheel](https://github.com/bhauman/lein-figwheel) is a great choice, interactive repl and debugger all inside Emacs.

For checking a function you can use the shortcut `Ctrl-c d d` to show the documentation and function signature.

[image: emacs_cider_docs]

Configure Cider cannot be easy at first but Figwheel makes the task easier, just un-comment the line under the comment `;; for CIDER` in your `project.clj` file of your Figwheel project, like this:

```
:profiles {:dev {:dependencies [[binaryage/devtools "0.7.2"]
                                  [figwheel-sidecar "0.5.4-7"]
                                  [com.cemerick/piggieback "0.2.1"]]
                   ;; need to add dev source path here to get user.clj loaded
                   :source-paths ["src" "dev"]
                   ;; for CIDER
                   :plugins [[cider/cider-nrepl "0.13.0"]]
                   :repl-options {; for nREPL dev you really need to limit output
                                  :init (set! *print-length* 50)
                                  :nrepl-middleware [cemerick.piggieback/wrap-cljs-repl]}}}
```

Then set Cider to use figwheel as repl:

`M-x` then launch the command `customize-variable`, the variable name to customize is: `cider-cljs-lein-repl` then set the variable to `Figwheel-sidecar`, save the configuration state and you are done.

It is important that Cider is the same version of the `cider-nrepl` plugin, at the time of this post they HAVE to be both version `0.13.0`.